# How to avoid error 'conflicts with a previous declaration' when using different namespaces in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, namespaces

I'm managing socket addresses with C++ and I specialize the `::sockaddr_storage` system library structure for example:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

namespace ns1 {
struct sockaddr_storage : public ::sockaddr_storage {
    void set_af(sa_family_t a_af) {
        this->ss_family = a_af;
}
};
} // namespace ns1

namespace ns1 {
// Variant 1: this compiles and works as expected
void f1() {
    sockaddr_storage ss;
    ss.set_af(AF_INET6);
}
} // namespace ns1

namespace ns2 {
// Variant 2: this also compiles and works without errors
void f2() {
    ns1::sockaddr_storage ss;
    ss.set_af(AF_INET6);
}
} // namespace ns2

using ::ns1::sockaddr_storage;

namespace ns2 {
// Variant 3: with declaring `using` it does not compile
void f3() {
    sockaddr_storage ss;
    ss.set_af(AF_INET6);
}
} // namespace ns2

int main() {}
```

For Variant 3 I get the following error message:

```
example$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Werror -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wdeprecated example.cpp
example.cpp:27:14: error: ‘struct ns1::sockaddr_storage’ conflicts with a previous declaration
   27 | using ::ns1::sockaddr_storage;
  |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h:33,
         from example.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h:191:8: note: previous declaration ‘struct sockaddr_storage’
  191 | struct sockaddr_storage
  |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
example.cpp: In function ‘void ns2::f3()’:
example.cpp:33:8: error: ‘struct sockaddr_storage’ has no member named ‘set_af’
   33 |     ss.set_af(AF_INET6);
  |        ^~~~~~
```

I expect that with `using ::ns1::sockaddr_storage;` the compiler will just do that for unspecified calls. I do not want to prefix all `sockaddr_storage` in my old code with the namespace name.

Why it compiles with error? What have I to do to avoid it? Why is there no conflict with Variant 1?

Comment: Don't infect the global namespace with `using ::ns1::sockaddr_storage;`. Simply apply the namespace before you use its components.

Comment: "_I expect that with using ::ns1::sockaddr_storage; the compiler will just do that for unspecified calls._": Do you mean `sockaddr_storage` (in contrast to `::sockaddr_storage`) with that? Or what is "_unspecified call_" supposed to mean?

Comment: `using ::ns1::sockaddr_storage` means `::ns1::sockaddr_storage` is now accessible as `sockaddr_storage`. It doesn't mean it is the *only* thing accessible as `sockaddr_storage` (and there are good reasons for that). If you have more than one, you've got a conflict.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes I mean `sockaddr_storage` without prefix `ns1::` as unspecified use.

Comment: There is, apparently, a class named `sockaddr_storage` introduced into the global namespace via `#include <sys,socket.h>`. Adding another one with `using ::ns1::sockaddr_storage;` adds another one to the global namespace. That’s the conflict: there are now two different definitions of `sockaddr_storage` in the global namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect of the *using-declaration*

```
using ::ns1::sockaddr_storage;
```

is that the compiler will do name lookup as if the entity named by `::ns1::sockaddr_storage` was declared (with its actual name) in the scope in which the using-declaration appears. How you refer to the entity doesn't matter. The effect of `using ns1::sockaddr_storage;` would be the same.

So `using ::ns1::sockaddr_storage;` tries to introduce a declaration of a class named `sockaddr_storage` into the global namespace scope which already has a class with the same name declared. It would not be possible to differentiate the two in any way, so this is always an error.

For usual name lookup the only difference between `::X` and `X` is that the lookup will look for `X` directly (and only) in the global namespace scope with the former syntax, while in the latter syntax `X` is searched in all contained scopes successively from inner to outer. Whether the name is then found via a using-declaration or a direct declaration is irrelevant. They are either way considered part of the lookup result set.

(There are a few additional difference between qualified and unqualified names like argument-dependent lookup for function calls, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

[The helpful answer from user17732522](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76077080/5014688) implies the obvious solution. Thank you :-) I moved the `using` statement to namespace `ns2`:

```
namespace ns2 {
// Variant 3

using ::ns1::sockaddr_storage;

void f3() {
sockaddr_storage ss;
ss.set_af(AF_INET6);
}
} // namespace ns2
```